# UseCallBack not getting current state in handleSaveRow of react-material-table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

//MRT Imports
import {
  MaterialReactTable,
  type MaterialReactTableProps,
  type MRT_ColumnDef,
} from "material-react-table";

//Material UI Imports
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import moment from "moment";

import useAxios from "@/services/api-request";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";
import { Autocomplete, Box, Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { ForwarderResponse } from "@/services/api-request/response-types";
import { convertToDDMMYYYY, removeEmptyValues } from "../General/helpers";

const ForwarderTable = ({
  warehouseOptions,
  tableData,
  currentYear,
  setReRun,
}: any) => {
  const { addToast } = useToasts();
  const [loadingDate, setLoadingDate] = useState("");
  const [warehouseId, setWarehouseId] = useState("");
  const { data, executeRequest, error } = useAxios<any>({
    autoRun: false,
  });

  const forwarderColumns = useMemo<MRT_ColumnDef[]>(
    () => [
      {
        accessorKey: "tripId",
        header: "Trip ID",
        size: 100,
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "loadingDate",
        header: "Loading Date",
        size: 180,
        Cell: ({ cell }) => {
          let date: any = cell.getValue();
          return convertToDDMMYYYY(date);
        },
        Edit: ({ cell, row }) => {
          let date: any = cell.getValue();
          date = date?.substring(0, 10);
          return (
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
              <DatePicker
                value={!!date ? dayjs(date) : ""}
                onChange={(date: any) => {
                  let newDate = new Date(date?.$d);
                  let formattedDate =moment(newDate).format(
                    "YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"
                  );
                  setLoadingDate(formattedDate);
                  row._valuesCache["loadingDate"] = formattedDate;
                  row.toggleSelected(row._valuesCache["loadingDate"]);
                }}
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
          );
        },
      },
      {
        accessorKey: "importer",
        header: "Importer",
        size: 100,
      },
      
      {
        accessorKey: "warehouse",
        header: "Warehouse",
        size: 150,
        Edit: ({ cell, row }: any) => {
          const { warehouseId } = row?.original;
          if (warehouseId) {
            row._valuesCache["warehouseId"] = warehouseId;
          }
          const defaultOption = {
            label: cell.getValue() ?? "",
            id: row.original?.warehouseId ?? "",
          };
          return (
            <Autocomplete
              options={warehouseOptions}
              size="small"
              defaultValue={defaultOption}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
              renderInput={(params: any) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  className=""
                  placeholder="Warehouse Name"
                />
              )}
              onChange={(event, value: any) => {
                row._valuesCache["warehouseId"] = value?.id;
                setWarehouseId(value?.id);
                row.toggleSelected(row._valuesCache["warehouseId"]);
              }}
            />
          );
        },
      },
  
      {
        accessorKey: "trackingUrl",
        header: "Tracking",
        size: 100,
      },
    ],
    [warehouseOptions]
  );
  const handleSaveRow: MaterialReactTableProps["onEditingRowSave"] =
    useCallback(
       ({ exitEditingMode, row, values }: any) => {
        const containerId: string = row.original._id;
        const { capacity, containerName, tripId, warehouse, ...data } = values;
        const currentWarehouseId = warehouseId;
        const currentLoadingDate = loadingDate;
        console.log("currentWarehouseId ", currentWarehouseId );
        console.log("currentLoadingDate", currentLoadingDate);

        const payload = {
          ...data,
          loadingDate: currentLoadingDate,
          warehouseId: currentWarehouseId ,
          containerId,
        };
        console.log("payload", payload);
        if (tripId) {
          payload["tripId"] = Number(tripId);
        }
        const filteredPayload = removeEmptyValues(payload);
        console.log("filteredPayload",filteredPayload)
        executeRequest({
          endpoint: `/container/update-container-data`,
          method: "PATCH",
          payload: filteredPayload,
        });
        exitEditingMode();
      },
      [ warehouseId, loadingDate, executeRequest]
    );


  return (
    <MaterialReactTable
      columns={forwarderColumns}
      data={tableData}
      enableEditing={true}
      editingMode="row"
      onEditingRowSave={handleSaveRow}
};

export default ForwarderTable;
```

I have a custom component in edit component of react-material-table.

1. When i update loadingDate using row._valuesCache["loadingDate"] the value is not passesd in       values of handleSaveRow.
2. I tried to declare a useState for loadingDate and get its value in callbackFn but the loadingDate value always remains empty inside callbackFn

Am i doing something wrong with row._valuesCache["loadingDate"]
Or
How can i get current value of loadingDate inside handleSaveRow